# Execute job spoon with software

Tags: jobs, spoon

I have a JOB done in SPOON, which is executed without problems in the command line, but I would like to know if there is any software in which I can execute these JOBS and go to see the execution visually. The idea is that for the most pleasant exploitation area these tasks are executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

- **Carte:**

Use the `carte` server which is shipped with the PDI. Install the PDI on any server, launch carte (specifying the port), then you can execute/view/stop/restart job/transformation from any browser. [Documentation is here](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Developer_Center/REST_API/Carte/010).

Of course you can launch a job/transformation from your own PDI. Just define a new `Slave server`, on the left panel, tab view, default username/password = cluster/cluster. Then each time you run a job/transformation, choose the carte server, instead of `Pentaho/local` in the `Run configuration`.

- **Loggin**

If you just want to follow job/transformation, you may use the database logging: Right-click any where, Parameters, Logging, Job/Transformation, then define a database, a table and a logging interval of 2 seconds.

Then every two seconds, the `line_read`, `line_written`, `errors`, and `log_field` are written to a database. This database can be read by an external process and displayed on the screen or on a browser.

This method is used in the [github/ETL-pilot](https://github.com/alaindebecker/ETL-pilot/blob/master/logging.jsp) which uses a tomcat (because you probably have a tomcat already running with a Pentaho server), but can easily be adapted to a nodejs or any other server. (If you do it and OpenSource it, please add a link to your work on our github).